# What unnecessary folders are possible to delete to clear a disk space

Tags: linux, linux-mint, memory, disk

Good day!

I have a problem with an insuficient disk space on Linux Mint 18.3

System didnt recognize that I deleted files and didnt update an empty space.
For now, I couldnt enter a login form - have these errors

```
Begin: Will now check root file system ... 

fsck from util-linux 2.27.1 [/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/sda5] 
fsck.ext4 -a -CO /dev/sda5 
/dev/sda5 contains file system with errors, check forced. 
[ 10.803397] random: crng init done | 0.3% /dev/sda5: 
Extended attribute block 2740536 has reference account 6, should be 5.
/dev/sd5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY. 
fsck exited with status code 4 done. 
Failture: File system check of the root filesystem failed 
The root filesystem on /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck 
[ 36.975860] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina 
[ 36.975860] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid 
[ 36.975860] usbhid: USB HID core driver 

BusyBox v 1.22.1 (Ubuntu......
```

I launched this command in command line

```
(initramfs) df -P
```

And got this

```
Filesystem 1024-blocks Used Available Capacity MountedOn
udev 1935236 0 1935236 0% /dev
tmpfs 391752 0 391752 0% /run
```

I suppose that a solution can be errase some files, but I dont know which not to corrupt a system.
After write `ls` in root folder I have this

```
dev scripts sbin etc run bin lib proc
root var usr lib64 conf init sys tmp
```

**Can you help me to solve it, all of my files are inside /home folder, and encrypted (I couldnt copy them from Windows tools)?**

Comment: Did you do a manual fsck of the root file system?

Comment: `fsck` doesnt exist like a command.. `sudo` as well

Comment: The pathname of the `fsck` command is right there in the message in front of you.

Comment: **My solution.** The problem was about insufficient disk memory space. I dont know why file system was crashed, but after an obvious decision to use Live USB like a way to launch `fsck`, I checked the broken partition manually, and then deleted installed libraries from /etc, in my case, npm and global packages. Then, it was possible to run a system in a normal mode, and clean other files from user home folder. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

None of your posted errors say anything about disk space problems, no need to erase any files.  `/dev` and `/run` are not your root filesystem.

Your output from `df -P` is showing those mounts are using 0% of their total capacity and zero blocks used, not using any space at all.

Your post does say that you have disk errors that need to be checked with a manual `fsck` of your file system.  The `fsck` command is available somewhere, that is the program that output the error you posted so you must have it installed.  It seems more like your machine won't boot due to your disk errors, and you are stuck in a limited, pre-boot environment.

If you are unable to boot into a usable environment, you should look into booting with a LiveCD or USB to be able to manually run `fsck` on your filesystems.

If you can get `fsck` to run successfully and it can repair the errors, you should be able to boot from that disk again.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I have a bootable USB. Can you tell me please how can I run this command `fsck` which can be applied for the installed system. I mean, when Im loading a USB, it will show me an install screen (GUI) with a Linux from USB. And should I use any flags? Maybe do you know a manual?

Comment: About `fsck`. I just need to launch it, and thats all? Or there is a bit of magic?

Comment: You say you get an install screen with your USB boot, you do not want to install but there should a "repair" option or something similar.  In the repair environment, you would want to verify the location of the filesystem you want to scan (in your output it is /dev/sda5, but in a different boot environment it could be named something else).  At the command line prompt, run `fsck.ext4 -y /dev/$PARTITION`.  The `-y` option tells `fsck` to answer "yes" to everything, omit that option if you want to be prompted for each error.